# How do I bypass the on Edit limitation (Google Script) for timestamp in the below Case?

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I know that there is a limitation with onEdit(e) function in google script.
I added a timeStamp onEdit function in my code and I want the data and time to be registered in my spreadsheet whenever I copy/paste(insert) data in it.

The problem is that the code works perfectly when I insert one row at a time but each time I add copy in multiple rows at a time the onEdit(e) function doesn't register.

Is there any way to bypass this?

Here is my timeTamp function(e) which I call with another onEdit(e) function.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  timeStamp(e)
}

function timeStamp(e) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = ss.getActiveCell();
  //1.Change 'Test' to be matching your sheet name
  if (r.getColumn() < 7 && ss.getName()=='Test') { // 2. If Edit is done in any column before Column (G)  And sheet name is Test then:
   var celladdress ='G'+ r.getRowIndex() 
    ss.getRange(celladdress).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!="Test" && e.range.columnStart<7)return;
  var ts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yy HH:mm")
  var l=e.range.getHeight();
  for(var i=0;i<l;i++) {
    sh.getRange(i+e.range.rowStart,7).setValue(ts)
  }
}
```

The solution suggested by TheMaster is probably a better way to go.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!="Sheet1"){return;}
  if(e.range.columnStart<7) {
    var ts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yy HH:mm");
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,7,e.range.rowEnd-e.range.rowStart+1,1).setValue(ts);
  }
}
```

I modified slightly to remove the getHeight() function

Comment: Thank you Cooper! It works like a charm! I see that you added a for loop to check each time if a change is made between that range. Did I understood correctly?

Comment: It doesn't actually check if a change is made for each row.  It all gets triggered by one onEdit() event.  You can't actually determine if the cell in each row has been changed because e.oldValue is only recorded for the upper left corner.  So it  pastes whatever you copy without checking for changes.

Comment: Let me add that I think over using the onEdit() can lead to problems.  So use it sparingly.

Comment: Ohh I see, I figured as much and also from what read about it. Question, in my above code I had a range for the time to be registered only if any changes are made from columns An:Fn. Is it possible to add this range limitation to your fix? (I tried to adapt your fix to what I currently have but it ends up breaking it.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @TheMaster  Good Idea I didn't think about that.